# 'no such child: pyval" error

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm working through a book (Python for Data Analysis) that has the following code in it. I'm getting an error 'no such child: pyval' when running the loop. Do I have a syntax error or something similar?

```
from lxml import objectify
path = 'Performance_MNR.xml'
parsed = objectify.parse(open(path))
root = parsed.getroot()
data = []
skip_fields = ['PARENT_SEQ', 'INDICATOR_SEQ', 'DESIRED_CHANGE', 'DECIMAL_PLACES']
for elt in root.INDICATOR:
    el_data = {}
    for child in elt.getchildren():
        if child.tag in skip_fields:
            continue
        el_data[child.tag] = child.pyval
        data.append(el_data)
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-88720283f598> in <module>()
      4        if child.tag in skip_fields:
      5            continue
----> 6        el_data[child.tag] = child.pyval
      7    data.append(el_data)
      8 

lxml.objectify.pyx in lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement.__getattr__ (src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c:3497)()

lxml.objectify.pyx in lxml.objectify._lookupChildOrRaise (src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c:5947)()

AttributeError: no such child: pyval
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also reading this book and run into the same problem. This worked for me.

```
skip_fields = ['PARENT_SEQ', 'INDICATOR_SEQ',
           'DESIRED_CHANGE', 'DECIMAL_PLACES', 'YEAR']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for elt in root:
el_data = {}
for child in elt.getchildren():
    if child.tag in skip_fields:
        continue
    el_data[child.tag] = child.pyval
    data.append(el_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'pyval' into 'text', that will be OK.

```
data=[]
skip_fields=['PARENT_SEQ','INDICATOR_SEQ','DESIRED_CHANGE','DECIMAL_PLACES']
for elt in root.INDICATOR:
    el_data={}
    for child in elt.getchildren():
        if child.tag in skip_fields:
            continue
        el_data[child.tag]=child.text
    data.append(el_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

.pyval tries to return the most appropriate python type, while .text returns a native python string

The file from the book "Python for Data Analysis" can be donwloaded from

https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/blob/2nd-edition/datasets/mta_perf/Performance_MNR.xml

or (raw)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/mta_perf/Performance_MNR.xml

The code (python 3.6)

```
from lxml import objectify
dataUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/datasets/mta_perf/Performance_MNR.xml'
from urllib.request import urlopen
retrievedString = urlopen(dataUrl).read().decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')


# XML() returns directly the root and not an element tree
parsed = objectify.XML(retrievedString)
# root = parsed.getroot()
data = []
skip_fields = ['PARENT_SEQ', 'INDICATOR_SEQ', 'DESIRED_CHANGE', 'DECIMAL_PLACES']
for elt in root.INDICATOR:
  el_data = {}
  for child in elt.getchildren():
    if child.tag in skip_fields:
      continue
    el_data[child.tag] = child.pyval
  data.append(el_data)

import pandas as pd
result = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

seems to work fine. The data types of the columns can be seen with

```
result.columns.to_series().groupby(result.dtypes).groups
```

=> {dtype('int64'): Index(['PERIOD_MONTH', 'PERIOD_YEAR'], dtype='object'), dtype('O'): Index(['AGENCY_NAME', 'CATEGORY', 'DESCRIPTION', 'FREQUENCY', 'INDICATOR_NAME',
       'INDICATOR_UNIT', 'MONTHLY_ACTUAL', 'MONTHLY_TARGET', 'YTD_ACTUAL',
       'YTD_TARGET'],
      dtype='object')}

Also replacing .pyval with .text works, but the datatypes will obviously change

=> {dtype('O'): Index(['AGENCY_NAME', 'CATEGORY', 'DESCRIPTION', 'FREQUENCY', 'INDICATOR_NAME',
       'INDICATOR_UNIT', 'MONTHLY_ACTUAL', 'MONTHLY_TARGET', 'PERIOD_MONTH',
       'PERIOD_YEAR', 'YTD_ACTUAL', 'YTD_TARGET'],
      dtype='object')}